# Issues parsing JSON from Client-Side back to JSONObject on Server-side

Tags: java, json, parsing

**Client Side (imitating)**

[image]

**Server Side**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class JsonRESTful extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsonService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getJson(InputStream inputStream) {

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Server Response", "Party on Wayne!");

        //Doesn't work :: cast exception
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(inputStream);

        System.out.println(json.toJSONString());

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(Status.OK.name(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Problem: Unsure of how to parse the JSON from Client back into JSONObject.**

```
Problem net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject


java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at com.thing.controllers.JsonRESTful.getJson(JsonRESTful.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: which library do you use for parsing json?

Comment: There's only one way to parse JSON.  How you interpret what was parsed is another matter.  What is your question?  And what does "Doesn't work" mean -- that's not an error description.

Comment: @HotLicks I just want to parse a simple ["key":"value"] String coming from the client into a JSONObject on the server side

Comment: @user230137 net.minidev.json.JSONValue.parse()

Comment: First off, dump the string going into `parse`.  Does the data look anything like what you're expecting.

Comment: @HotLicks comes in exactly how I would expect it

Comment: @user230137 Cast exception. although when examining it from the debugger it appears to be copasetic with the JSON form I would expect. All documentation using this parser shows casting here should work correctly (as coded up above)

Comment: Can you put the cast Exception message here so we can know the correct type returned by parse()?

Comment: You use two library org.json and net.minidev.json?

Comment: You're using the json-smart parser (`net.minidev.json.JSONValue`) but then try to cast it to a class from the `org.json.simple` package. That won't work, read https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/wiki/MigratingFromJsonSimpleToJsonSmart

Comment: Yep, you're using two different class libraries.  Had you done as you're supposed to and included the exception trace in your original question this would have been resolved within seconds.  (And had you bothered to look at that trace the question would have been unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have imported the wrong class. You should do :

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject
```

not

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Comment: ... and remove whatever JAR provides `org.json.simple` from your class/build path.